# Does this two useEffects makes a long loop?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am writing a React app. I used two `useEffects`. One `useEffects` gets data from firebase and changes "cartItems" and "totalAmount".

The second `useEffect` has these two dependencies and it runs when these dependencies change and overwrites data model.

I think it makes loop with no point (I might be wrong). How can I solve it and make it efficient? I would like to transform to Redux Toolkit Actions, but first I would like to do it in vanilla React.

```
useEffect(() => {
    fetch('https://italianhouse-1aef0-default-rtdb.europe-west1.firebasedatabase.app/cart.json')
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(data => {
      console.log(data)
      const keys = Object.keys(data.cartItems)
      keys.forEach(key => dispatch(cartActions.getCartData(data.cartItems[key])))
      dispatch(cartActions.setFetchedTotalAmount(data.totalAmount))
      
    })
  }, [dispatch])

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch('https://italianhouse-1aef0-default-rtdb.europe-west1.firebasedatabase.app/cart.json', {
            method: 'PUT',
            body: JSON.stringify({cartItems: cartItems, totalAmount: totalAmount}),
            headers: {
                'content-type': 'application/json'
            }

        })
  }, [cartItems, totalAmount])
```

Answer (score 0):

- Looks like your first useEffect pushing you in the loop.
- Passing an empty array as the second argument to useEffect, which makes it only run on the mount and unmount.

  useEffect(() => {
  ...
  }, []);

Answer (score 0):

I have solved it by using additional boolean

```
let isInitial = true

useEffect(() => {
    fetch('https://italianhouse-1aef0-default-rtdb.europe-west1.firebasedatabase.app/cart.json')
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(data => {
      const keys = Object.keys(data.cartItems)
      keys.forEach(key => loadedMeals.push(data.cartItems[key]) )
      dispatch(cartActions.replaceCart(loadedMeals))
      dispatch(cartActions.setFetchedTotalAmount(data.totalAmount))
      isInitial = false
    })
  }, [dispatch])
  
  useEffect(() => {
    if (isInitial) return
    
    fetch('https://italianhouse-1aef0-default-rtdb.europe-west1.firebasedatabase.app/cart.json', {
            method: 'PUT',
            body: JSON.stringify({cartItems: cartItems, totalAmount: totalAmount}),
            headers: {
                'content-type': 'application/json'
            }

        })
        
  }, [cartItems, totalAmount])
```